# How to get range of elements in a list in KDB?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

For example, I have this list:

```
test:(8;12;15;19;10)
```

How may I select elements 2 to 4?

When I try `list[2;4]` it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

indexing a list is by far the fastest way.

```
q)a
8 1 9 5 4 6 6 1 8 5 4 9 2 7 0 1 9 2 1 8 8 1 7 2 4 5 4 2 7 8 5 6 4 1 3 3 7 8 2..
q)\t do[100000;2 3 sublist a]
109
q)\t do[100000;a 2 3 4]
15
```

So just follow your list with a list of indexes. BTW you can create indexes with `til`

```
q)til 2
0 1
q)2+til 2
2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sublist for this

```
test:(8;12;15;19;10);
2 3 sublist test
```

This will return three elements from the list starting at index 2.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Manish, `til` is the best bet here. You can define a simple function `range` using `til` to give the index range :

```
q)test:(8;12;15;19;10)

q)range:{x+til 1+abs[y-x]}   //include the start and end index 
q)test range[2;4] 
15j, 19j, 10j
```