# Get range of elements in KDB using variables

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Why I can't use variable inside array ranges in KDB?

```
test:1 2 3 4 5
```

This example won't work:

```
pos:3;
test[1 pos]
```

but this way it will work

```
test[1 3]
```

Comment: It doesn't work with semi-colon also. it says:
 'type 
(wrong type)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525768/how-to-get-range-of-elements-in-a-list-in-kdb

Comment: It doesn't help as it doesn't use variables there also variable with sublist doesn't work also.

Comment: It's a simple extrapolation. `a+til b` gives you the list you require to get your range. `a` and `b` are variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, when you use test[1 3], (1 3) is a list. So vector variable requires a list.

```
   q) list1:1 3
   q) test[list1]
```

So you have to use:

```
   q)n:3
   q)list1:(1;n)
   q)test[list1]
   q)test[(1;n)]  / alternate way
```

For detail explanation about why only semicolon doesn't work and why we require brackets '()',check my answer for this post:

[kdb/q: how to reshape a list into nRows, where nRows is a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531488/kdb-q-how-to-reshape-a-list-into-nrows-where-nrows-is-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

To understand what you're asking, consider:

```
1 2 3 7
```

That is a simple list of integers. Now consider:

a 2 3

Where `a` is a vector. The above indexes into `a`. Easy. Now say you want to have that `2 3` list as a variable

b:2 3
   a b //works!

You are specifically asking about how to get a range from a list, this is covered in [How to get range of elements in a list in KDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525768/how-to-get-range-of-elements-in-a-list-in-kdb)

In that answer, use variables to create your index list and use the result to index into `a`